# Python equivalent for Matlab vector slice

Tags: matlab, numpy, slice

I have the following code in Matlab (I do not have Matlab), that apparently constructs integers by sampling sequences of binary values:

```
velocity_LUT_10bit = zeros(2^10,1);
for n = 1:length(velocity_LUT_10bit),
    imagAC = bin2dec(num2str(bitget(n-1,9:-1:6))) - bitget(n-1,10)*2^4;       % Imaginary part of autocorrelation: signed 5-bit integer
    realAC = bin2dec(num2str(bitget(n-1,4:-1:1))) - bitget(n-1, 5)*2^4;       % Real part of autocorrelation: signed 5-bit integer
    velocity_LUT_10bit(n) = velNyq_CF*angle((realAC+0.5)/16 + 1i*(imagAC+0.5)/16)/pi;
end;
```

I am having trouble understanding the `bitget()` function. From the [docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitget.html?searchHighlight=bitget&s_tid=doc_srchtitle#inputarg_bit), the first arg is the sampled sequence, while the second arg specifies the range of the sample, but I am confused about what the slicing `x:-y:z` means. I understand it from the [docs](https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html) as "sample from index *x* to *z*, going right to left by strides of *y*". Is that correct?

What would be the numpy equivalent of `bin2dec(num2str(bitget(n-1,9:-1:6)))`? I understood I should be using `numpy.packbits()`, but I am a bit stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an Octave session:

```
>> for n=0:3:15,
   bitget(n,1:1:5)
end
ans =
   0   0   0   0   0
ans =
   1   1   0   0   0
ans =
   0   1   1   0   0
ans =
   1   0   0   1   0
ans =
   0   0   1   1   0
ans =
   1   1   1   1   0
```

This is just the binary representation of the number, with a sliced selection of the bits.  Octave/Matlab is using the 'start:step:stop' syntax.

The rest converts the numbers to a string and from binary to decimal:

```
>> num2str(bitget(13,5:-1:1))
ans = 0  1  1  0  1
>> bin2dec(num2str(bitget(13,5:-1:1)))
ans =  13
```

`bitget(n-1,9:-1:6)` must be fetching the 9th to 6th bits (powers of 2) in reverse order.  So for a number up to 2^10-1, it's pulling out 'bits' 1-4, 5, 6-9, and 10.

---

I'm not familiar with Python/numpy binary representations, but here's a start:

```
>> num2str(bitget(100,10:-1:1))
ans = 0  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  0  0
In [434]: np.binary_repr(100,10)
Out[434]: '0001100100'
```

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't thought of trying it in Octave to troubleshoot it.

Comment: `np.binary_repr` may be start, giving a similar string version.